# Java 2d game programming struggle

Tags: java, class, game-engine

In my 2d game (Slick2d java library) I have defined a sprite class (that stands for enemyCharacter - to be more specific - its a red square that chases white square - the player).
Now i want in my state (one of the class names PlayState that stands for my play state :P) to make some kind of loop that is making more and more enemyCharacters on the Gameboard after i press "1" for example.

I understand all renderings,updates, inites (ive already done that game) but i want to upgrade it

Do i have to storage these objects in some kind of arraylist or how to do that? And do i have to make obj1, obj2, obj3 etc?

For instance, i got class called SpriteClass...
Now, in my class called PlayStateClass i want to do (this is a simple code, i know its wrong written but thats not the point):

```
public class SpriteClass {
public SpriteClass (float enemySpeed) {
this.enemySpeed = enemySpeed;
}

public class PlayStateClass {
Sprite Class object1 = new Sprite Class(20); // How to do that in loop?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will create 10 instances of `SpriteClass` in an `ArrayList` called `sprites`.

```
ArrayList<SpriteClass> sprites = new ArrayList<SpriteClass>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sprites.add(new SpriteClass(20));
}
```

...and to perform an operation on each sprite:

```
for (SpriteClass sprite : sprites)
{
    sprite.doSomething(someArgument);
}
```

Comment: And how do i use that object? I mean for instance i want all objects to do some method... how do i evoke that?